# What will happen if I abort creation of a clustered index

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning

I am in the process of deploying an update of our C# MVC application to our production environment. One of the steps involves addition of a primary key constraint to the identity column of a large table (~10GB). This is automatically creating a clustered index, and the ALTER TABLE statement is still running after two hours.

Our users will be returning to the application shortly, and I'm worried that if the ALTER TABLE statement is still running then they will see deadlock failures in the application.

Is there a way I can tell how far through the clustered index creation is?
What will happen if I abort the ALTER TABLE command?

I am using SQL Server 2014 Standard.

Update: The alter table statement did eventually complete (without impacting users too much), but I'm still interested to learn more in case I run into a similar problem in the future.